# How to stop my phone from auto-correcting my writing?

Tags: auto-correct

I have several Android phones, with different Android versions. I am writing short messages in several languages (Spanish, Catalan, English, German, Italian, ...) and I am really fed up with Android trying to outsmart me. A simple message takes me ages to write because I need to fight the auto-correction mechanism, or change the language, or whatever.

But if I disable all languages in the auto-correction settings, it still tries to auto-correct in English. Why?

Auto-correction is not for me. I do not want auto-correction, period. Not in English, not in **any** language. Is this possible?

Comment: Which device/keybroard are you using? Check also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/how-do-i-turn-off-auto-complete-when-texting

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what keyboard app you're using. If you're using **Google Keyboard** (the default on Nexus devices), go into its settings. Go to the **Text correction** section and click **Auto-correction**. Choose **Off** from the list.

If you prefer, you could install a keyboard that supports using multiple languages at the same time, such as SwiftKey.